# Index Column Multiple of two

Tags: powerbi

I have a very simple problem that I can not seem to solve in Power BI.  I simply want to add an index column to my table where each value is repeated once, starting from 1. So it would look like this:

```
Index    Teams     Score
1        Team A    1
1        Team B    0
2        Team C    2
2        Team D    1
3        Team B    0
3        Team D    0
4        Team A    1
4        Team C    3
```

I tried creating an index column by increments of 0.5 hoping to be able to round down all the half values but power bi would only let me create an index column in increments of integers. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Query Editor, add an Index Column starting from 2 with increment 1 and then transform the column with Integer-Divide by 2.

```
let
    [...]
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Previous Step", "Index", 2, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Integer-Divided Column" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index", {{"Index", each Number.IntegerDivide(_, 2), Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Integer-Divided Column"
```

Under the Transform tab:

[image: Standard Transforms]